# How to change style of RadioButtons created by AlertDialog Builder setSingleChoiceItems

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating an AlertDialog that will show a list of radio buttons to pick one. It's working as I need, except that when it's created, the radio buttons are shown to the left of the item text, and I would like them be shown to the far right of the Dialog

Here's the result I'm getting (don't have enough reputation to embed images) http://img.ctrlv.in/img/15/09/29/560ab269bad4a.jpg

This is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
String[] items = new String[]{"1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001"}
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, getItemSelectedCallback(false, items));
builder.create().show();
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `I'm creating an AlertDialog that will show a list of radio buttons to pick one.` So, basically, a Spinner.

Comment: In essence, yes, but I need the View that will open the dialog on click to be a custom view, and I'd prefer to not have to refactor it to transform it into a spinner

Comment: Couldn't you simply use a Spinner instead of a custom Dialog? OR simply search for `android custom dialog`. The official docs provide all the necessary info and more. Really. A great piece of doc.

Comment: Again, I can't use a Spinner without refactoring a great deal of code. I don't think it's warranted given I just need to move one radio button from the left to the right. There must be some way to edit the style of the AlertDialog

Comment: If you did the Google search I suggested you, you would have already found your answer.

Comment: It's already done, so it doesn't matter now. But I didn't need to. In any case, I found what I wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this is possible with zero refactoring and without using a Spinner. What I had to do is create an array adapter that transforms the items into a custom layout.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.checked_text_view, items);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, 0, getItemSelectedCallback(false, items));
```

For the custom layout I used a CheckedTextView

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
/>
```

And this got the job done